# Make a SignalR service persistent in the client with Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I've been trying to make real-time connections with SignalR in Angular 11.2.4. with a Asp.net Core back-end.
It was working perfectly if I kept the SignalR service talking to a single component, but I would like to have one that is persistent in the whole Client even after destoying the component.

When I create the hubConnection instance `this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()`, I would like to make it persistent between components and not to recreate it everytime I need the SignalR service. Is there a way to make the service's variables persistent ?

I tried to store into the local storage the `this.hubConnection`, but every handlers (ex: `this.hubConnection.on('SendSignal'` ) are null (seems logic since all the references have been destroyed), should I make a wrapper for the whole class ? It seems to be an overkill for what I'm trying to do..

I might be missing something as it's my first experience with Angular, but the session storage seems to be the answer, or maybe defining a static class.

Thanks !

Comment: As far as I know, angualr also contains a singleton service, you could set the hubconnection in that singleton service and use it in different components to achieve your requirement, more details, you could refer to this [article](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: That's actually what I was using, but everytime the page is refreshed everything is gone. Is there a possibility to save the whole service inside the session storage ?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no way to achieve this.  A client will always disconnect when refreshing a page, and connects to SignalR again when the next page is loaded.